# Typescript dynamic useReducer

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a reusable `useReducer` hook with typings.

This is my current code:

```
type State<T> = {
  data?: T
  isLoading: boolean
  error?: string
}

type Action<T> =
  | { type: "request" }
  | { type: "success"; results: T }
  | { type: "failure"; error: string }

function reducer<T>(state: State<T>, action: Action<T>): State<T> {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "request":
      return { isLoading: true }
    case "success":
      return { isLoading: false, data: action.results }
    case "failure":
      return { isLoading: false, error: action.error }
  }
}

export function useFetchState<T>() {
 return useReducer(reducer<T>, {isLoading: false});
}
```

As you can see, the hook should be used for holding fetch state but the data should be dynamic, so that it can be used in different contexts:

```
const [videoFetch, dispatchVideo] = useFetchState<Video[]>()
const [userFetch, dispatchUser] = useFetchState<User[]>()
```

My problem is, that the expression `reducer<T>` is failing due to *Error:(26, 20) TS2345: Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer'.*, but without specifying `T`, the data type is unknown.

I'm not sure, how this situation is called in TypeScript land, so I hope that someone can explain to me, if and how I can achieve, what I want.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @ChristopherPeisert https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L858

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reducer<T>` is not grammatically invalid. `reducer` is just `reducer`. There is no such thing like `reducer<T>`. The compiler is understanding it as `reducer < T >` (comparison operators), which it believes is most likely a boolean value when completed as an expression. That is why it is complaining "Argument of type `boolean` is not assignable to parameter of type `Reducer`" -- the compiler discovers a boolean value, or a boolean value suspect, at the position where a value of type `Reducer` (which is just your `reducer` variable) should appear.

Not passing the generic parameter is wrong either. The type inference of, for example, `videoFetch` would be wrong: `videoFetch` is inferred as `State<{}>` (probably `State<unknown>` in more recent versions. I'm not 100% sure about this though).

So where should the generic parameter `T` actually be? Note that the type inference actually happens on `useReducer`. So we just need to manually provide the correct type parameters of `useReducer`:

```
export function useFetchState<T>() {
  return useReducer<Reducer<State<T>, Action<T>>>(reducer, { isLoading: false });
}
```

In this case you can check that the type of `videoFetch` are correctly inferred. So are the types of all other variables.